# Fill entire QWebView with always-visible semi transparent black rectangle

Tags: qt, pyside

I have a class that inherit from `QWebView`, I have re-implemented the `paintEvent` to draw a rectangle around certain web elements on a web page.

Now I want to totally fill that custom class widget with a black semi-transparent rectangle, and keep such rectangle always visible no matter how much the user scrolls the web page.

My problem is that I'm not sure which method returns the `QRect` with the correct information I need. Neither how to calculate the visible area to paint according to the size of the widget and the scroll position... or if there is a way to paint what I need above the scrollable area.

(Don't worry about giving code snippets in C++, I understand code in C++)

Comment: Are you asking how to get the `QRect` of the QWebView?

Comment: Not exactly but the **visible part** of the widget

Comment: so you want to cover part of the webpage? Your explanation is not totally clear.

Comment: Not part but the entire part only visible for the user, and keep the rect visible when the user scrolls.

Comment: @shackra. What do you mean by "visible"? Perhaps you should add a screenshot to your question showing exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this by myself. [`QWebPage::viewPortSize)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#viewportSize-prop) returns the information I need, and when I'm drawing the rectangle, I use a `0x 0y` coordinates as starting point. And it works!